# SDL test project Build Failure Error Message using Eclipse C/C++ IDE 2020-06 on Windows 10

Tags: c++, eclipse, sdl

*This is my first programming course in over 20 years, so I am basically clueless.

I am trying to complete the last project in the course which includes installing and configuring SDL.  Right now all I have is the basic "Hello World" code.  I get the error when I add #include .
When I installed SDL, I copied the SDL2 folder and the entire lib folder to MinGW-w64 - as instructed by a tutorial.
I have MinGW-w64 installed.  Here is the build error:
C:/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
I've been googling for hours and cannot seem to find any help.*

Edit:

Thank you both so much for your quick responses.

[Here is what I did in settings:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSG8R.png)

Do I need to put an 'l' in front of these items?

I got some help elsewhere and added #define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED.  This allowed the project to build, but it still doesn't run. I get nothing at all when I try to run it.  I tried calling SDL_GetError(), but still nothing.

Comment: You forgot to link against `-lSDL2main` (you need following linker flags, in this order: `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`). Also make sure you're using the proper prebuilt library (your compiler is x64, make sure your SDL is also built for x64).

Comment: Regarding the edit: `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` is not the intended way to use SDL. You can use it if you don't like SDL replacing main, but the intended way is to link `-lSDL2main` instead. It wouldn't prevent your code from running though, so the problem is somewhere else. Does it run if you start the .exe manually (by double-clicking in the explorer) rather than from Eclipse?

Comment: I got it!! I had forgotten to copy the SDL2.dll file to the MinGW bin folder.  It works perfectly now!

Comment: Putting it in the same directory as your .exe should also work. Remember that the people to whom you'll distribute your app won't have MinGW installed.

Comment: Ahaa.  I read that before too, but they didn't explain clearly why the way you just did.  Where is that exactly? Is that the src folder?

Comment: Where the `.exe` file is. I'm not sure where eclipse puts it, you'll have to look around your project directory.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I need to do some reading to get a better handle on the basics. :-)

Answer (score 1):

also make sure your main has the following signature:
int main(int, char**) - SDL is pretty militant about it